# [Caffe-CNN]How to get gradients of the output w.r.t. to a convolutional layer?

Tags: python, caffe, gradient

I'm trying to implement this paper - https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.02391 using Python. For that I want to get gradient of the output of a specific class with respect to the last convolutional layer. I came across the following usage of backward() function.

```
label = np.zeros((1, 6))
label[0, interested_class] = 1
net.backward(**{net.output[0]: label})
```

Assuming I have six classes in my network.

However it gives gradient w.r.t to the input layer.

I tried to use the following usage but it is not giving the desirable output.

```
label = np.zeros((1,6))
label[0,interested_class] = 1
net.backward(end=conv, **{net.output[0]:label})
```

Precisely, I want to get the gradient of output layer w.r.t *conv* layer values.

Any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out how to do this by reading [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31324739/finding-gradient-of-a-caffe-conv-filter-with-regards-to-input) and [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/caffe-users/diff[0$2Ctarget$2C0$2C0]$20$3D$201%7Csort:relevance/caffe-users/5iwXJ3NmHJA/KGdKcBrpyJUJ). Here is the code.

```
layer_name = 'conv' #Convolutional layer of interest
class_label= 4 # the class of interest
label = np.zeros((1,6))
label[0,interested_class] = 1    
grads= net.backward(diffs= [layer_name], **{net.outputs[0]:diff})
gradients = grads[layer_name]
```

Hope this will be helpful!

Comment: I wrote a blog post for this implementation(http://sandaw89.blogspot.sg/2017/08/gradcam-implementation-in-pycaffe.html). Anyone can find more details from there.